# Netstat command for multiple ports under windows and unix

Tags: windows, unix, command, port, netstat

How can I determine the services which are listening on a port bigger than 8000 using the netstat command under windows and unix?

Could you help me out, please?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you need to run a command console as administrator. Then execute

```
netstat -ab
```

The b lists the executable program that is doing the listening. you should be able to match that to the services.

I don't think netstat is selective on the ports, if you are not seeing any beyond 8000 then there is no activity or listening there.

This works on windows. Not sure if this is also the case on unix.